# Ubuntu halts after Booting

Tags: 11.10, boot

My Ubuntu 11.10 halts for about 10seconds after booting and this happen each time I login, just during the first hour of usage. This situation is like this: The screen starts to dim and all applications stop working Music stops, browsing, even the mouse pointer disappears for about 10 secs and it happens 2 or 3 time consequently, my laptop specs is as follows:

HP Pavilion dv6000, Nvidia Geforce 8400GS, 2.50 Ghz core 2 duo, 2.00 GB RAM.

Thanks in advance for your help.
Regards,

Answer (score 1):

disable screensaver and power saving options,make sure it never powers down without you telling it to.. i end up kicking my machine because it wont turn on again after it hibernates or goes to sleep. im hoping the canonical team will fix this soon.